# Display Document Library Folder contents on a different Sharepoint 2007 Site

Tags: 2007

What I want to do seems incredibly simple, but I am getting nowhere quickly searching and reading about this.

I need to list some policy documents on a Sharepoint page on our corporate intranet.  This is in web application http://intranet  The documents are stored in a folder in a document library in our HR Team Site - that's in http://teams/sites/HR.

There seem to be a variety of methods for displaying the content of the folder on pages within the same site or site collection (e.g. Content Query Web Part, List View Web Part, Data View Web Part), but automatically displaying this in a different site collection seems very difficult, without spending a lot of money on a third party web app, or spending many hours writing one myself.

Am I missing something here?  I thought Sharepoint was about leveraging your content and data across the enterprise.

Comment: By the way - if someone were to upvote this question I would have enough reputation to upvote the useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Site Collections in SharePoint create silos, across which it is difficult to share content.

Still, there are a couple advanced options that require more than the standard "drag and drop Web Part" action.

Some options (your mileage may vary):

- Use a Page Viewer Web Part (requires some work to make it look pretty)
- create copies of the documents, with automatic synchronized updates ("send to" option). You'll need to do this for each document.
- use Web services, which will work across site collections on a same domain.
- host all your intranet in a single site collection.
- use my cross-site snapshot trick, available here:
  http://sp2010.pathtosharepoint.com/SharePoint-User-Toolkit

Note: the last option (snapshot) will not allow you to open folders. You'll need to directly link to the folder content:
http://teams/sites/HR/LibraryName/FolderName

Answer (score 0):

It is, but there are boundaries.

From an architecture standpoint, it makes the most sense to store the files on the intranet where all people would have access.  The files in http://teams/sites/HR would be the working documents.  When the files are revised in the team site, the updated versions would get placed on the intranet site as the official current policy.

Comment: Which is great, but right now that isn't the way our team sites work.  I can see it changing, perhaps even over the next year, but in the meantime, it would be great if I could get the technology to work with our practices, rather than having to change the whole organisation to fit Sharepoint's limitations.  And even if we did that, if we have multiple site collections within our Intranet web application, the problem remains - silos.

Comment: Also, we would like to be able to surface content from our team sites to our intranet pages to promote cross organisational working.  This needn't be based on "finished" documents - discussions, blogs etc. would be nice candidates for this.

Answer (score 0):

This thread implies that you can with a bit of fiddling get the dataview to pull across site collection boundaries - I can't say I've done that, though.

http://www.sharepointdev.net/sharepoint--design-customization/instert-a-dataview-webpart-from-another-site-17134.shtml

Other options not mentioned would include using an RSS feed from the document library, or using a Search to return results from the library.

It wouldn't be too hard to write your own web part, though.

Comment: Andy, I checked out your link, all the comments are about doing it within a site collection.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, yes, I misread one of the posts.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using the Content Editor web part to insert an iframe that displays content from the 2nd site collection. It may be a bit fiddly to make things look exactly right though.