# How can I display SharePoint document library items including folders on company non-SharePoint Internet site

Tags: web-services

I would like to create a document library on an internal SharePoint farm either, on wss 3.0 or SharePoint Foundation, and display the library items/folders on an Internet site which is hosted on a different server which is using classic asp/asp.net technology. In my research I got [Jared's content](http://weblogs.asp.net/jaredroberts/archive/2009/02/06/display-sharepoint-documents-on-your-company-internet-site.aspx) which is nice but I thought there might be other way of doing it using the Client Object Model (i.e. in SP 2010) or something else. Could any one think of a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good suggestions in this related question: [Display Document Library Folder contents on a different Sharepoint 2007 Site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7880/display-document-library-folder-contents-on-a-different-sharepoint-2007-site/13620#13620).

Answer (score 1):

The options I can think of are Web Services and Client Object Model. If you are a SharePoint developer the Client Object Model will be the more attractive. If your background is more ASP.NET and .NET generally, you will probably lean toward using the Web Services (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705814.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the local(internal) sharepoint farm is not in DMZ, so Client Side script is not options as it references to internet URL and executes in the browser.

We have create a server side custom control

1. to read the list items and render (grid, list..etc)
2. to download the file and push it to the client (byte stream)

So, you have to got with a similar option like you have researched as your internet site acts as an interface to the internal sharepoint site and the end users